# How to realize a multi-page wizard with client-side controller "rules" in JSF2 or GWT2?

Tags: javascript, forms, jsf, gwt, conditional-statements

In (JSF2 + jQuery) or in GWT: 
What would be the best way to realize a ***multi-page form wizard*** with explicitly specified form controller "rules" running on the client-side?

The goal is:

1. form with 3 pages, each containing 'prev'/'next' buttons and finally 1 'submit' button.
2. all form items have unique ids for addressing/accessing them.
3. for client-side form control there are 2 kind of control "rules" specified in a central place and stored somehow:

   - active behaviour of 1 item (modifying 1+ other items):

     ```
     WHEN form item x is checked/changed/text=="MyText"
     THEN show/hide/modifyTextOf item y and item z.
     ```
   - passive behaviour of 1 item (waiting for 1+ events):

     ```
     WHEN ((itemA.propX is 'blah') AND (itemB.text()=="Yeah!") OR
           (itemC is checked) AND (itemD.value() >= 10))  
     THEN 
         self.setVisible(true); /self.hide(true);   //and
         itemF.setText("It's Magic!"); 
         ... 
     END-THEN
     ```

The action triggering resp. event listening is intented to be on a per-page basis -- one later enhancement could be to also run "cross-page modifications/listenings", e.g.
itemA on page 1 triggers some action on itemC on page 3.

*How would you define, persist (XML,JSON?) this logic and finally run it within 
a client-side form controller?*

Answer (score 0):

[PrimeFaces](http://www.primefaces.org) has a ready-to-use component for this, the [`p:wizard`](http://www.primefaces.org:8080/prime-showcase/ui/wizard.jsf).

With regard to control rules, make use of the `rendered` attribute.

Comment: Thank you very much for the link to this widget I wasn't aware of ... But, if I got it right, with 'rendered' attrib I've the cond. rules (a) fixed at runtime, and (b) dispersed all over the faces' code.

Is there a dynamic way to "inject" rules from a central place *at runtime*? 

Goal: "Cond. rules" should be definied by "form admins" via jsf2 admin tool and stored all toghether somewhere. Now I'm wondering how to bring the rules into pre-defined, almost fixed faces!?

-- Or is this "injection" only possible with addit. face-generating component?

@all: Do you also know a solution for GWT?

Comment: By the way, do someone know about (a) a good JSF2 or GWT2 spreadsheet widget mimicking 'MS Excel' functionality [I know PrimeFaces' 'Spreadsheet' widget, but there is neither multi-cell selection-&-modification nor function application supported], and (b) a good calendar widget comparable to PrimeFaces 'Schedule' but more like Apple iCal or Google Calendar???

Thank you very much for any hints!

Comment: Really no suggestions or tips for the issues stated in my last 2 comments???  -- Especially the JSF2-related, dynamics issue questioned in my 1st comment would be very important to me.  Thanks a lot again.